# Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information. on Net Core MVC Assembly GetTypes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have a console app in a solution...I'm trying to load the assemblies in the solution to retrieve a list of Types from each assembly in the Solution.

```
var types = Assembly.LoadFrom(namepath).GetTypes()
```

Simple line of code...works fine for class libraries but when I try to load the assemblies for a web app I get the error:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   `LoaderExceptions` property for more information.

The loader exception is:

> *Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.0.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.*

Any idea how I can pull a list of Types from a net core web app assembly without getting this error?

Comment: Did you have an luck with this?

Comment: Not really I ended up just going a different route to get what I needed...the solution provided below doesn't work and no one ever provided me any any alternatives.